# groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.predic8.schema.Element#setType.?

Tags: web-services, groovy, wsdl

I need to parse the WSDL file dynamically.

My code are Here:

```
package com.wsdl.migration;
import com.predic8.schema.Schema;
import com.predic8.wsdl.Definitions;
import com.predic8.wsdl.Fault;
import com.predic8.wsdl.Message;
import com.predic8.wsdl.Operation;
import com.predic8.wsdl.Part;
import com.predic8.wsdl.PortType;
import com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser;

import groovy.lang.GrabResolver;
import groovy.lang.MetaMethod;
import javax.xml.namespace.*;

public class FullWSDLParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();

        //https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/Time_Tracking/v23.0/Time_Tracking.wsdl
       Definitions defs = parser.parse("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl");



        out("-------------- WSDL Details --------------");
        System.err.println("TargenNamespace: \t ---- > " + defs.getTargetNamespace());
        if (defs.getDocumentation() != null) {
            out("Documentation: \t\t" + defs.getDocumentation());
        }
        out("\n");
        //defs.getQName().getQualifiedName()
        // For detailed schema information see the FullSchemaParser.java sample.
        out("Schemas: ");
        for (Schema schema : defs.getSchemas()) {
            out("  TargetNamespace: \t" + schema.getTargetNamespace());
        }
        out("\n");

        out("Messages: ");
        for (Message msg : defs.getMessages()) {
            System.out.println("  Message Name: " + msg.getName());
            System.out.println("  Message Parts: ");
            for (Part part : msg.getParts()) {
                out("    Part Name: " + part.getName());
                out("    Part Element: " + ((part.getElement() != null) ? part.getElement() : "not available!"));
                out("    Part Type: " + ((part.getType() != null) ? part.getType() : "not available!" ));
                out("");
            }
        }
        out("");

        out("PortTypes: ");
        for (PortType pt : defs.getPortTypes()) {
            System.err.println("  PortType Name: " + pt.getName());
            System.out.println("  PortType Operations: ");
            for (Operation op : pt.getOperations()) {
                System.err.println("    Operation Name: " + op.getName());
                System.out.println("------------QNAME - > "+op.getQName());
                System.err.println("    Operation Input Name: "
                    + ((op.getInput().getName() != null) ? op.getInput().getName() : "not available!"));
                System.out.println("    Operation Input Message: "
                    + op.getInput().getMessage().getQname());
                System.out.println("    Operation Output Name: "
                    + ((op.getOutput().getName() != null) ? op.getOutput().getName() : "not available!"));
                System.out.println("    Operation Output Message: "
                    + op.getOutput().getMessage().getQname());
                System.out.println("    Operation Faults: ");
                if (op.getFaults().size() > 0) {
                    for (Fault fault : op.getFaults()) {
                        System.out.println("      Fault Name: " + fault.getName());
                        System.out.println("      Fault Message: " + fault.getMessage().getQname());
                    }
                } else out("      There are no faults available!");

            }
            out("");
        }
        out("");

        out("Bindings: ");
        for (Binding bnd : defs.getBindings()) {
            out("  Binding Name: " + bnd.getName());
            out("  Binding Type: " + bnd.getPortType().getName());
            out("  Binding Protocol: " + bnd.getBinding().getProtocol());
            if(bnd.getBinding() instanceof AbstractSOAPBinding) out("  Style: " + (((AbstractSOAPBinding)bnd.getBinding()).getStyle()));
            out("  Binding Operations: ");
            for (BindingOperation bop : bnd.getOperations()) {
                out("    Operation Name: " + bop.getName());
                if(bnd.getBinding() instanceof AbstractSOAPBinding) {
                    out("    Operation SoapAction: " + bop.getOperation().getSoapAction());
                    out("    SOAP Body Use: " + bop.getInput().getBindingElements().get(0).getUse());
                }
            }
            out("");
        }
        out("");

        out("Services: ");
        for (Service service : defs.getServices()) {
            out("  Service Name: " + service.getName());
            out("  Service Potrs: ");
            for (Port port : service.getPorts()) {
                out("    Port Name: " + port.getName());
                out("    Port Binding: " + port.getBinding().getName());
                out("    Port Address Location: " + port.getAddress().getLocation()
                    + "\n");
            }
        }
        out("");
    }

    private static void out(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

And My Gradle file for Dependency is here :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-support:2.0.8'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
  compile 'org.json:json:20160810'
  compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.0.1'
  compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api', version: '1.0.1.Final'
  compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.predic8/soa-model-core
    compile group: 'com.predic8', name: 'soa-model-core', version: '1.5.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections
compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.5-RC2'
}
```

My error Log  :

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.predic8.schema.Element#setType.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class javax.xml.namespace.QName]
    [class groovy.xml.QName]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMostSpecificParams(MetaClassImpl.java:3268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:3221)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:3164)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getNormalMethodWithCaching(MetaClassImpl.java:1380)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCaching(MetaClassImpl.java:1295)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1065)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MultipleSetterProperty.setProperty(MultipleSetterProperty.java:54)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2694)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3775)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.setProperty(XMLElement.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:532)
    at com.predic8.schema.Element.parseAttributes(Element.groovy:50)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:41)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.predic8.schema.ModelGroup.parseChildren(ModelGroup.groovy:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:46)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.predic8.schema.ComplexType.parseChildren(ComplexType.groovy:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:46)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.predic8.schema.Schema.parseChildren(Schema.groovy:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:46)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.predic8.wsdl.Types.parseChildren(Types.groovy:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:46)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.predic8.wsdl.Definitions.parseChildren(Definitions.groovy:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement.parse(XMLElement.groovy:46)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.XMLElement$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser.parseLocal(WSDLParser.groovy:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at com.predic8.soamodel.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.groovy:35)
    at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser.super$2$parse(WSDLParser.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
    at com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser.parse(WSDLParser.groovy:24)
    at com.wsdl.migration.FullWSDLParser.main(FullWSDLParser.java:39)
```

I get this code from net.But i can get the output only use thier WSDL url, when i chage with other wsdl file URL,i throws me error,says some thing related with QName.I am newbee for wsdl and xml also. i can not find the acctual problem .So please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too have faced this problem.. Dont know the solution, but the thing I suspect is,
The class QName is defined in two different jars.
1. class javax.xml.namespace.QName
2. class groovy.xml.QName
i.e., from xml library of java and groovy. Groovy during runtime finds both and thus the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and the is problem with groovy version,

Please try to downgrade groovy version.